# winecfg no longer has Windows versions/compatibility modes below Windows XP?

Tags: wine

Invoking `env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/testprefix /opt/wine-devel/bin/winecfg` or any other `winecfg` binary on the system causes the dialog to provide no Windows versions below Windows XP (e.g. Windows 95 and 98 are missing). I expect a `wine` prefix to be set up in `$HOME/testprefix` with this command and all of the usual versions (from Windows 2 to 10) to be available.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 with `wine` binaries from their PPA. In `PlayOnLinux` all windows versions are available.

Comment: 2.0 and according to `synaptic` it's 2.0.0~ubuntu16.10.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows below XP is only supported in 32-bit prefixes which are created by setting the `WINEARCH` environment variable to `win32`, e.g.

```
env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=$HOME/someprefixname winecfg
```

(taken from https://superuser.com/a/864922/298426)